# restTemplate java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "None" does not contain '/'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

Ok first of all code (its mega simple):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")

public class HelloController {

private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloController.class);
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

    logger.info("ELO ELO");
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    String url = "http://192.168.0.200:8000/GPIO/11/function/in";
    //String url = "http://192.168.0.200:8000/GPIO/11/function";
    //restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
    String test = "";

    restTemplate.postForObject(url, null, String.class);



    logger.info(test);
    return "hello";
}
```

Next example that I'm not a crazy man here is response from postman (chrome):

[image]

And at the end full error log:

> type Exception report
>
> message Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "None" does not contain '/'
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "None" does not contain '/'
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:927)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "None" does not contain '/'
>     org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:697)
>     org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:305)
>     org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.getContentType(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:113)
>     org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:84)
>     org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:492)
>     org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:447)
>     org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:295)
>     pl.piquarium.mvc.HelloController.printWelcome(HelloController.java:35)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:439)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:427)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/8.0.3 logs.

Request headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utma=212787668.2094541430.1400264829.1400264829.1400268775.2; __utmz=212787668.1400264829.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host:192.168.0.200:8000
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:2
Content-Type:None
Date:Fri, 16 May 2014 22:37:16 GMT
Server:WebIOPi/0.7.0/Python3.2
```

Comment: Where's your view named `hello`? Did you intend to make this a `RestController` or use `@ResponseBody`?

Comment: My view is ok if I comment lane with restTemplate.post it load without problem

Comment: Post the entire response headers from that GPIO endpoint (Raspberry Pi?). I suspect that service is sending back no or a bogus content type.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16887656/head.txt Here is head

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting headers like below,

```
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);//or any other required
 HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(null, headers);
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 String url = "http://192.168.0.200:8000/GPIO/11/function/in";
 String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url,request,String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the server is returning an invalid content type of `None` instead of something like `text/plain`, and Spring REST is choking on it. You will need to add a custom message converter for the `None` type, not use a typed query and parse the response object yourself, or get the Pi people to fix their broken Web server.